# VLCJ no reproduce video cuando usa getClass ().getResource()

Tags: java, video, vlcj

Estoy haciendo un juego, pero este depende de unos vídeos; no tengo experiencia previa en manejo de vídeos en Java, así que usé VLCJ, ya que fue lo primero que encontré en YouTube. De todos modos, el asunto es que cuando uso `getClass(). getResource()` y ejecuto el .jar, este no carga el vídeo. Entonces, lo que necesito es que el vídeo se pueda abrir desde el .jar.

```
String ruta1 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").getFile(); //No funciona (necesito que sirva)

String ruta2 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").toExternalForm());  //No funciona (necesito que sirva)

String ruta3 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").toString());  //No funciona (necesito que sirva)

String ruta4 = getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").getFile().replace("/", "\\"); //Funciona (No es lo que necesito)

String ruta5 = new File("src\\media\\introVideo.mp4").toString(); //Funciona (No es lo que necesito)
```

El error que obtengo cuando uso ruta1, ruta2 y ruta3 son los siguientes:

```
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Could not open D:\Programming\HyperDance\\D:\Programming\HyperDance\build\classes\media\introVideo.mp4 with libdvdcss.
libdvdread: Can't open D:\Programming\HyperDance\\D:\Programming\HyperDance\build\classes\media\introVideo.mp4 for reading
libdvdnav: vm: failed to open/read the DVD
[000000001c5ed6a0] filesystem stream error: cannot open file D:\Programming\HyperDance\\D:\Programming\HyperDance\build\classes\media\introVideo.mp4 (Invalid argument)
[000000001c5e3d00] main input error: Your input can't be opened
[000000001c5e3d00] main input error: VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///D:/Programming/HyperDance/%2FD%3A%2FProgramming%2FHyperDance%2Fbuild%2Fclasses%2Fmedia%2FintroVideo.mp4'. Check the log for detail
```

**Carpetas**

- HyperDance

  - src

    - media

      - introVideo.mp4

**Snippet:**

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.EmbeddedMediaPlayer;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.embedded.windows.Win32FullScreenStrategy;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

public class Test extends JFrame {

  static Test frame;
  static Canvas canvas;

    public Test() {
        canvas = new Canvas();
          canvas.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        add(canvas);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frame = new Test();
          frame.setSize(1047,615);
          frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          frame.setVisible(true);
          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
          Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
          MediaPlayerFactory mpf = new MediaPlayerFactory();
          EmbeddedMediaPlayer emp = mpf.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer(new Win32FullScreenStrategy(frame));
            emp.setVideoSurface(mpf.newVideoSurface(canvas));
          //↓ ¿Cómo soluciono la importación del vídeo? ↓
            emp.prepareMedia(new Object().getClass().getResource("/media/introVideo.mp4").getFile());
          //↑ El parámetro solo acepta Strings ↑
            emp.play();
    }
}
```

**Resumiendo:**

- Necesito reproducir un video desde un .jar.
- El video se reproduce cuando no uso `getClass().getResource()`, pero necesito usarlo para acceder al vídeo desde el .jar.
- La pregunta: ¿Cómo reproducir un vídeo usando VLCJ desde un .jar?

Comment: Parece que el fichero no se ha incluido en el jar. Prueba lo siguiente: abre el fichero jar con un descompresor (cambia la extensión a ZIP si te resulta más fácil así) y comprueba que el vídeo está dentro y que la ruta es la que esperas.

Comment: Si está dentro...

Comment: Si todavía no funciona, puede deberse a permisos de la carpeta...

Comment: ya funciono hace 2 semanas xd